# Get the index of array with known value of the structure

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have this class with several attributes something like this:

```
public class FileIn {

public String id;

public void setID(String id_) {
    id = id_;
}

public String getID() {
    return id;
}

...

}
```

There are 20 attributes.
Then i put this data in one ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<FileIn> dfor_A = new ArrayList<FileIn>();
```

Well, later i need to get the index of one element, but i know the id

```
dfor_A.get(-unknow index-).getID();
```

How can i search and get the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**
I think you have to loop

```
/*function perform operation dfor_A.indexOf(item.id);*/
public int getIndexOf(String id,List dfor_A)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < dfor_A.size(); i++) {

     FileIn fi = dfor_A.get (i);
     if (fi.getID().equals (id)) {
       return i;  // this is the index
     }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**Solution 2 :**
if you think about good performance of it. I suggest you to use advanced features

**Step 1 :Implement Comparator**

```
public class FileInCustomComparator implements Comparator<FileIn> {
   @Override
   public int compare(FileIn fileIn1, FileIn fileIn2) {
      return fileIn1.getId()-fileIn2.getId();//id consider as int here
   }
}
```

**Step 2 :Sort the list**

```
Collections.sort( for_A /*list here*/, new FileInCustomComparator());
```

**Step 3 :Search the Sorted list using optimized inbuilt algorithm**

```
public void search(String key,List list) {
  System.out.println("\nSearching for " + key);

  int result = Collections.binarySearch(list, key);
  if (result >= 0)
     System.out.print(" Found at index " + result);
  else
     System.out.print(" Not found [" + result + "]");
}
```

Comment: Looks very slow for a lot of items.  Also as you are already looping, whey not just keep a `counter` for the index?  Finding the `indexOf` an item when you already have found it would slow things down even more.

Comment: Yeah, the loop is the last resourse, this is gonna be running over 5000 items and for get just 1 value is too much waste of time

Comment: I tried that first, but the data its changing with the time and his order is not something i can control, so if a item got x index in first running after 3 or 4 hours it changes, so thats not a option.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map e.g. HashMap

```
Map <String, FileIn> map = new HashMap <> ();
map.put (fileIn.getID (), fileIn);
```

later

```
FileIn fileIn = map.get (fileIn.getID ());
```

If you really want to keep an ArrayList, then you will need to loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < dfor_A.length; i++) {

    FileIn fi = dfor_A.get (i);
    if (fi.getID().equals (id)) {
       return i;  // this is the index
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works, please consider to upvote and/or accpet my answer

Comment: Yeah, i upvote but sadly it doesn't work. I have to figure it out